# Angular UI Router: How to stop reloading based on query parameters change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is my ui-router configuration:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('search.filter.results', {
    url: '/results?profileId&keywords',
    views: {
      'profiles@': {
        templateUrl: 'profile-list/profile-list.html',
        controller: 'ProfileListCtrl'
      },
      'profile-summary@search.filter.results': {
        templateUrl: 'profile-list/profile-summary/profile-summary.html'
      },
      'profile-details@search.filter.results': {
        templateUrl: 'profile-list/profile-details/profile-details.html',
        controller: 'ProfileDetailsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

`ProfileListCtrl` has the following method:

```
$scope.showProfileDetails = function(profileId) {
  $state.go('search.filter.results', { profileId: profileId });
};
```

The problem is, when this method is executed, `ProfileListCtrl` is instantiated and the view is reloaded.

**I would like the reload to happen only if the `keywords` query parameter changes, but not when  the `profileId` parameter changes.**

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You have setup your state url to accept two parameters. Anytime you change either of them, the page will reload.Maybe if i know what your trying to achieve it would make things a little more clear. 
I believe ShowProfileDetails is triggered by clicking one of the profiles.
Use a conditional to check if the keywords param is the same as the current $state.params.keywords. If it is then don't run $state.go.

Comment: @nathvarun I have a list of profiles. When `profileId` doesn't exist in the query string, only profiles summaries are shown. If, for example, `?profileId=123` - I would like to show profile details for this particular profile (and profile summaries for the other profiles). When user "expands" a profile (to see its details), the resulting URL should have that `profileId` set. If all profiles details are closed, the URL shouldn't have `profileId` in the query string. Does this make sense?

Comment: aah okay so your problem is coming with the nested views.You want one of the views to show you the clicked users profile while the other continues to show the summary of the other users.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: split this state into 2 states.

1. The *"parent"* keeping the `profileId`,
2. the *"child"* working with `keywords`.

Until the `profileId` is not changed, the parent controller won't be re-instantiated.

I created this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ozxXQZ1suAC0Cv62fkL1?p=preview) with this simplified states definition:

```
.state('profile', {
    url: '/results/:profileId',
    views: {
      'profiles@': {
        //templateUrl: 'profile-list/profile-list.html',
        template: '<div>'
        ...
        '<div ui-view=""></div></div>',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      },
    }
  })
.state('profile.results', {
    url: '/?keywords',
    views: {
      '': {
        //templateUrl: 'profile-list/profile-list.html',
        template: ...
        controller: 'ProfileListCtrl'
      },
    }
  })
```

*NOTE: state defintion here is simplified, to just show the split. Not all the details. Also, the child state target parents unnamed view `ui-view=""`, because these should be nested. Finally, parent could even be abstract*

This approach also will require some small adjustments of the url. It is not working well if the child url defintion would start with `?` like: `url: '?keywords'`. So I used different pattern:

```
/results/profileId-value/?kewords=abc
```